# DialogflowCX- @sys.any Doesn't Grab Everything In Second Flow

Tags: dialogflow-cx

@sys.any is not working reliably when it's used outside of the main flow.

[image: Flow to subflow]

I created an intent with 9 different words, and every word has been highlighted with the @sys.any entity type.

[image: Training Phrases]

The idea of @sys.any is to grab ANY input the user does, however, it's only grabbing some words. If I put the same intent in the main flow at the start, it is able to grab anything I type correctly.

However, if I use the same exact intent in a second flow on the same project, it only grabs *some* words. If I type "pyramid," the intent is triggered. If I type "train", it's not a match. "Cat" is not a match. "Sandwich" is not a match. "Power" is not a match. "Soda" IS a match.

If I create an entirely new agent with the same exact intent, and have it go to a second flow, it's able to capture everything correctly on the second flow. It almost looks like my secondary flow is bugged. On my "bugged" secondary flow I can put the same intent on it on the start page, and it still only grabs some of the words, not all of them.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried copying your what you did on your 1st screenshot and the intent captures the words you have tried. I'm not sure if I did the reproduction correctly. Can you show the reproduction steps? How is the flow configured? Or if possible can you export your agent? So the community can easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't export the agent due to NDA. I also am not able to reproduce the issue myself. I made a new agent with the same scenario and intent, and sys.any is working properly on brand new flows. On the "bugged flow" even if I put the sys.any intent at the start, it's not able to capture all of the words. But of course that scenario and intent works fine on a fresh agent even in the second flow. The same intent that fails on the "bugged flow" works fine on the main flow of the same agent. During my testing, I made sure the sys.any intent was the ONLY route and with no parameters.

Comment: I have an update. I have pages later on in the flow that also use sys.any. I actually have four different intents that use sys.any. If I change the intents on the pages later on to all use the same sys.any intent, then the sys.any at the start works properly. It shouldn't interact like this because the pages later on are not connected to the first page that utilizes a sys.any intent. Either way, it solves my problem, well, kind of. It's more of a work-around than a solution.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, you can post this as the answer and accept it. So other users in the future can easily see the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pages later on in the flow that also use sys.any. I actually have four different intents that use sys.any. If I change the intents on the pages later on to all use the same sys.any intent, then the sys.any at the start works properly. It shouldn't interact like this because the pages later on are not connected to the first page that utilizes a sys.any intent. Either way, it solves my problem, well, kind of. It's more of a work-around than a solution.